# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject() cannot deserialize the string properly

Tags: c#, dictionary, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

I'm trying store this Dictionary as json:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Word>> _cateList;
//class Word
public Word{
        private string _title;
        public string Title
        {
            get
            {
                return _title;
            }
            set
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)){
                    throw new Exception();
                }
                _title = value;
            }
        }

        //key:category, value:definition
        private Dictionary<string,string> _categorizedDefinition;
        public Dictionary<string, string> CategorizedDefinition
        {
            get
            {
                return _categorizedDefinition;
            }

        }
}
```

So basically there 3 dictionaries inside each other.
First I serialize the dictionary with some sample code with JsonConvert.Serialize, the output json file looks like this:

```
//json code
{
  "biology": {
    "biology": {
      "Title": "Tree",
      "CategorizedDefinition": {
        "Biology": "A plant"
      }
    }
  }
}
//c# code
Dictionary<string, string> temp = new Dictionary<string, string>()
  { {"Biology", "A plant" } };
Word wd = new Word("Tree", temp);
_cateList.Add("biology", new Dictionary<string, Word>()
  {
       {"biology", wd }
  });
```

But when I use these code to deserilize the json:

```
_cateList = await DataJsonHandler.LoadFromJsonFile();
//method code
public async static Task<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Word>>> LoadFromJsonFile()
{
    Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Word>> tempDic;
    StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("CategorizedWords.json");
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(awaitfile.OpenStreamForReadAsync()))
    {
    //this lines got the same string in the original json file
     string lines = sr.ReadToEnd();
     tempDic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Word>>>(lines);
    }
     return tempDic;
}
```

And serilize it again, I got:

```
{
  "biology": {
    "biology": {
      "Title": "Tree",
      "CategorizedDefinition": null
    }
  }
}
```

Not sure what happened here to make the dictionary in Word object gone, did I miss something?

Comment: Just a note: never do `throw new Exception();` throw an `ArgumentException` instead in your case with information about the parameter name and the reason for throwing the exception. To save you and your colleagues some frustration in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the setter on `CategorizedDefinition`. You need that in order for newtonsoft to set the property value when deserializing.

```
public Dictionary<string, string> CategorizedDefinition
{
    get =>  _categorizedDefinition;
    set => _categorizedDefinition = value; // < --magic here
}
```

But since you are using a constructor for the `Word` class, you may be forgetting to set _categorizedDefinition inside that constructor. Something like this would do:

```
// constructor
public Word(string title, Dictionary<string, string> categorizedDefinition)
{
    // ignoring title for now, because it already works.
    this._categorizedDefinition = categorizedDefinition;
}

private Dictionary<string, string> _categorizedDefinition
public Dictionary<string, string> CategorizedDefinition
{
    get =>  _categorizedDefinition;
    set => _categorizedDefinition = value;
}
```

Comment: Thx for the answer! Just add the setter on CategorizedDefinition and the problem is solved